# JSONKit changing float values on decoding JSON object from webservice in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, jsonkit

Float values are getting changed after parsing with `JSONKit`. The problem occurs after calling `objectFromJSONString` or `mutableObjectFromJSONString`.

The JSON response is fine before this method is triggered in `JSONKit.m`:

```
static id _NSStringObjectFromJSONString(NSString *jsonString, JKParseOptionFlags parseOptionFlags, NSError **error, BOOL mutableCollection)
```

Original response:

```
"value":"1002.65"
```

Response after calling `objectFromJSONString`:

```
"value":"1002.6500000001" or sometimes "value":"1002.649999999 "
```

Thanks.

Comment: A `float` ***cannot*** represent the number 1002.65 exactly.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an issue.

**The value `1002.65` can not be represented exactly using a IEEE 754 floating point number**.
Floating-point numbers are converted to their decimal representation using the [printf](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/printf.3.html) format conversion specifier %.17g.

From the [Docs](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit):

> The C double primitive type, or IEEE 754 Double 64-bit floating-point,
>   is used to represent floating-point JSON Number values. JSON that
>   contains floating-point Number values that can not be represented as a
>   double (i.e., due to over or underflow) will fail to parse and
>   optionally return a NSError object. The function strtod() is used to
>   perform the conversion. Note that the JSON standard does not allow for
>   infinities or NaN (Not a Number). The conversion and manipulation of
>   floating-point values is non-trivial. Unfortunately, RFC 4627 is
>   silent on how such details should be handled. You should not depend on
>   or expect that when a floating-point value is round tripped that it
>   will have the same textual representation or even compare equal. This
>   is true even when JSONKit is used as both the parser and creator of
>   the JSON, let alone when transferring JSON between different systems
>   and implementations.

Source: See this thread https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/issues/110

Solution: You can specify a precision, while converting float to string for output. [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will be a better choice or use some printf solutions like in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

use float fixed point representation like,

```
 NSLog(@"value = %.2f",floatvalue);
```

now it will show value = 1002.65